# Startup Applications not running proccess (GoodSync)

Tags: startup, autostart

I have defined the following .desktop file in ~/.config/autostart:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Version=9.5.7
Name[en_US]=GoodSync server
Name=GoodSync server
Comment[en_US]=Start GoodSync server
Comment=Start GoodSync server
Exec=/opt/goodsync-release-x86_64/gs-server
Terminal=true
Type=Application
Categories=Utility;Application;
X-GNOME-Autostart-enabled=true
```

But the gs-server is not being run at startup. If I ran it from terminal manually, there is no problem. What could be the reason that this configuration does not work (maybe because I have it in opt)?